# Would an anisotropic speed of light possibly allow light to escape a black hole?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, speed-of-light, escape-velocity

It has been proposed that light coming toward the earth is near infinite but that light outgoing is near 1/2 c.  I know we cannot directly measure the one-way speed of light, but if anisotropy were true, wouldn't we notice the effects as light traveled near black holes?  Or does the curvature of space-time mean that the trajectory of light is independent of it's speed?

Comment: proposed where, and by who?

Comment: Can you explain why you think anisotropic light propagation is necessary or desirable?  Is the current theory deficient in some way? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Answer (score 3):

Black holes are a prediction of general relativity, and it is a fundamental assumption in GR that the speed of light is a local invariant i.e. it is independent of direction and indeed anything else.

The problem with your question is that if you assume the speed of light depends on direction this means GR is wrong and cannot describe the universe, and that means predictions of GR like black holes will be incorrect as well. So it is meaningless to ask whether a direction dependent speed of light could allow light to escape a black hole. The only way to answer this would be to come up with a new theory that allowed a direction dependent speed of light, then see if that new theory predicted anything like a black hole. I am not aware that any such theory exists.

For the record we should note that there is no experimental evidence that the speed of light is direction dependent, and no physicist I know takes the suggestion seriously.